# Scala's type system and the input to FunctionN

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-systems

I am wondering if there is a way of patching over an apparent inconsistency in Scala's handling of Function1 and Function2..N.

For a `Function1`, say `Int => String`, the *parameter list* (Int) is not identical to Int (even if the two are isomorphic), yet the compiler will infer the input as bare Int (see the code below).

For `Function2..N`, say 
    val f: (String, Int) => String = ???
the compiler will not infer any type for the input parameter list. In particular, there is no ParameterList[String, Int] even though it is isomorphic to tuples of (String, Int) and any other wrapper you fancy putting around Strings and Ints.

My first question is, is there is a reason it is like this (or is this something that exists on a list of scala todos)? i.e. why can Function1 be deconstructed into input and output type but not Function2 and does anybody want to fix that?

Are there any work arounds. Specifically, in the code below, is there a way to make invoke2 work?

```
package net.jtownson.swakka

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import shapeless.ops.function._
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, _}

class TypeclassOfFunctionTypeSpec extends FlatSpec {

  // Here, we know the return type of F is constrained to be O
  // (because that's how the shapeless FnToProduct typeclass works)
  def invoke1[F, I <: HList, O](f: F, i: I)
                               (implicit ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, I => O]): O = ftp(f)(i)

  // So let's try to express that by extracting the input type of F as FI
  def invoke2[FI, I <: HList, O](f: FI => O, i: I)
                                (implicit ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[FI => O, I => O]): O = ftp(f)(i)

  "Invoke" should "work for a Function1" in {

    // Here's our function (Int) => String
    val f: (Int) => String = (i) => s"I got $i"

    val l = 1 :: HNil

    // this works
    val r1: String = invoke1(f, l)

    // So does this. (With evidence that the compiler sees the function parameter list (Int) as just Int
    val r2: String = invoke2[Int, Int::HNil, String](f, l)

    r1 shouldBe "I got 1"
    r2 shouldBe "I got 1"
  }

  "Invoke" should "work for a Function2" in {

    // Here's our function (String, Int) => String
    val f: (String, Int) => String = (s, i) => s"I got $s and $i"

    val l = "s" :: 1 :: HNil

    // this works
    val r1: String = invoke1(f, l)

    // But this does not compile. There is no expansion for the type of FI
    // (String, Int) != the function Parameter list (String, Int)
    val r2: String = invoke2(f, l) 
    /*
    Error:(...) type mismatch;
    found   : (String, Int) => String
      required: ? => String
        val r1: String = invoke1(f, l)
    */

    r1 shouldBe "I got s and 1"
    r2 shouldBe "I got s and 1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `Function2#tupled` and `Function2#curried` methods?

Comment: Yes, I am:-) And also that tupled does not exist on Function1. Presumably this is because the ability to express the type of Function1's _input_ (as the bare type) means tupled is not needed. Poor old Function2..N lack this. In this sense tupled feels like a workaround. I guess what I am wondering, though, is is there a good reason for the discrepancy between Function1 and 2 in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

`Int => String` is syntax sugar for `Function1[Int, String]`, `(String, Int) => String` is syntax sugar for `Function2[String, Int, String]`, `((String, Int)) => String` is syntax sugar for `Function1[(String, Int), String]` aka `Function1[Tuple2[String, Int], String]`.

You can help Shapeless to resolve `FnToProduct` instances if you define implicit conversion

```
implicit def tupledFnToProduct[FI1, FI2, O, Out0](implicit
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[Function2[FI1, FI2, O], Out0]
  ): FnToProduct.Aux[Function1[(FI1, FI2), O], Out0] =
  new FnToProduct[Function1[(FI1, FI2), O]] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(f: Function1[(FI1, FI2), O]) = ftp((x, y) => f(x, y))
  }
```

Then you can call `invoke2` with `.tupled`

```
val f: (String, Int) => String = (s, i) => s"I got $s and $i"

val l = "s" :: 1 :: HNil

val r2: String = invoke2(f.tupled, l)

r2 == "I got s and 1" //true
```