# Express function of arbitrary arity in vanilla Scala 3

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, currying, scala-3

Trying to grasp Scala 3 type system.
Question:

- Is it possible to write a single universal `def curry(f: ???) = ...` function that accepts `f` of any arity and returns a curried fn? No compiler plugins, no external fancy libs, just a function of N-arity expressed in plain Scala 3?
- I look at this Haskell example https://riptutorial.com/haskell/example/18470/an-n-arity-curry that does smth similar to what is needed.

(purpose of this question is not to use any external lib - purpose is *to learn* functional programming concepts with Scala 3 as a tool. Got a feeling that this might be related to dealing with args as tuples or some conversion of fn to tupled fn ? i feel there is some symmetry between fn args and a concept of tuple ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On contrary to Haskell, in Scala there are different functional types `(X1, ..., Xn) => Y` (aka `FunctionN[X1, ..., Xn, Y]`) and `((X1, ..., Xn)) => Y` (aka `Function1[TupleN[X1, ..., Xn], Y]`). For the latter (in order to transform them into `X1 => ... => Xn => Y` aka `Function1[X1, Function1[..., Function1[Xn, Y]...]]`) you can use [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html), [inline methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html), and [compile-time operations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html)

```
import scala.compiletime.{erasedValue, summonFrom}

type Reverse[T <: Tuple] = ReverseLoop[T, EmptyTuple]

inline def reverse[T <: Tuple](t: T): Reverse[T] = reverseLoop(t, EmptyTuple)

type ReverseLoop[T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match
  case EmptyTuple => S
  case h *: t => ReverseLoop[t, h *: S]

inline def reverseLoop[T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple](x: T, acc: S): ReverseLoop[T, S] =
  inline x match
    case _: EmptyTuple => acc
    case x: (_ *: _) => x match
      case h *: t => reverseLoop(t, h *: acc)

type Curry[T <: Tuple, Y] = CurryLoop[T, T, EmptyTuple, Y]

inline def curry[T <: Tuple, Y](f: T => Y): Curry[T, Y] =
  curryLoop[T, T, EmptyTuple, Y](f, EmptyTuple)

type CurryLoop[T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y] = T1 match
  case EmptyTuple => Y
  case h *: t => h => CurryLoop[t, T, h *: S, Y]

inline def curryLoop[T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y](
  f: T => Y,
  acc: S
): CurryLoop[T1, T, S, Y] = inline erasedValue[T1] match
  case _: EmptyTuple => summonFrom {
    case _: (Reverse[S] =:= T) => f(reverse(acc))
  }
  case _: (h *: t) => (h: h) => curryLoop[t, T, h *: S, Y](f, h *: acc)
```

Testing:

```
// compiles
summon[Curry[(Int, String, Boolean), String] =:= (Int => String => Boolean => String)]

val f: ((Int, String, Boolean)) => String = t => s"${t._1}, ${t._2}, ${t._3}"
val g = curry(f)
g: (Int => String => Boolean => String) // checking the type
g(1)("a")(true) // 1, a, true
```

[Scala 3: typed tuple zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355407/scala-3-typed-tuple-zipping)

---

Alternatively, you can still use good old [type classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/type-classes.html)

```
trait Reverse[T <: Tuple]:
  type Out <: Tuple
  def apply(t: T): Out

object Reverse:
  type Aux[T <: Tuple, Out0 <: Tuple] = Reverse[T] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[T <: Tuple, Out0 <: Tuple](f: T => Out0): Aux[T, Out0] =
    new Reverse[T]:
      override type Out = Out0
      override def apply(t: T): Out = f(t)

  given [T <: Tuple](using
    reverseLoop: ReverseLoop[T, EmptyTuple]
  ): Aux[T, reverseLoop.Out] = instance(t => reverseLoop(t, EmptyTuple))

trait ReverseLoop[T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple]:
  type Out <: Tuple
  def apply(t: T, acc: S): Out

object ReverseLoop:
  type Aux[T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Out0 <: Tuple] =
    ReverseLoop[T, S] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Out0 <: Tuple](
    f: (T, S) => Out0
  ): Aux[T, S, Out0] = new ReverseLoop[T, S]:
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(t: T, acc: S): Out = f(t, acc)

  given [S <: Tuple]: Aux[EmptyTuple, S, S] = instance((_, acc) => acc)

  given [H, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple](using
    reverseLoop: ReverseLoop[T, H *: S]
  ): Aux[H *: T, S, reverseLoop.Out] =
    instance((l, acc) => reverseLoop(l.tail, l.head *: acc))

trait Curry[T <: Tuple, Y]:
  type Out
  def apply(f: T => Y): Out

object Curry:
  type Aux[T <: Tuple, Y, Out0] = Curry[T, Y] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[T <: Tuple, Y, Out0](g: (T => Y) => Out0): Aux[T, Y, Out0] =
    new Curry[T, Y]:
      override type Out = Out0
      override def apply(f: T => Y): Out = g(f)

  given [T <: Tuple, Y](using
    curryLoop: CurryLoop[T, T, EmptyTuple, Y]
  ): Aux[T, Y, curryLoop.Out] = instance(f => curryLoop(f, EmptyTuple))

trait CurryLoop[T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y]:
  type Out
  def apply(f: T => Y, acc: S): Out

object CurryLoop:
  type Aux[T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y, Out0] =
    CurryLoop[T1, T, S, Y] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y, Out0](
    g: (T => Y, S) => Out0
  ): Aux[T1, T, S, Y, Out0] = new CurryLoop[T1, T, S, Y]:
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(f: T => Y, acc: S): Out = g(f, acc)

  given [S <: Tuple, Y](using
    reverse: Reverse[S]
  ): Aux[EmptyTuple, reverse.Out, S, Y, Y] =
    instance((f, acc) => f(reverse(acc)))

  given [H1, T1 <: Tuple, T <: Tuple, S <: Tuple, Y](using
    curryLoop: CurryLoop[T1, T, H1 *: S, Y]
  ): Aux[H1 *: T1, T, S, Y, H1 => curryLoop.Out] =
    instance((f, acc) => h1 => curryLoop(f, h1 *: acc))

def curry[T <: Tuple, Y](f: T => Y)(using
  curryInst: Curry[T, Y]
): curryInst.Out = curryInst(f)
```

Testing:

```
// compiles
summon[Curry.Aux[(Int, String, Boolean), String, Int => String => Boolean => String]]

val c = summon[Curry[(Int, String, Boolean), String]]  // compiles
summon[c.Out =:= (Int => String => Boolean => String)] // compiles

val f: ((Int, String, Boolean)) => String = t => s"${t._1}, ${t._2}, ${t._3}"
val g = curry(f)
g: (Int => String => Boolean => String) // checking the type
g(1)("a")(true) // 1, a, true
```

---

A method `tupled` transforming `(X1, ..., Xn) => Y` into `((X1, ..., Xn)) => Y` can be implemented as a [transparent macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#relationship-with-transparent-inline). A macro being transparent (this corresponds to [whitebox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html#blackbox-and-whitebox-macros) in Scala 2) means that it can return a type more precise than declared.

```
import scala.quoted.*

transparent inline def tupled[F](f: F): Any = ${tupledImpl('f)}

def tupledImpl[F: Type](f: Expr[F])(using Quotes): Expr[Any] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val allTypeArgs = TypeRepr.of[F].typeArgs
  val argTypes    = allTypeArgs.init
  val argCount    = argTypes.length
  val returnType  = allTypeArgs.last

  val tupleType = AppliedType(
    TypeRepr.typeConstructorOf(Class.forName(s"scala.Tuple$argCount")),
    argTypes
  )

  (tupleType.asType, returnType.asType) match
    case ('[t], '[b]) => '{
      (a: t) => ${
        Apply(
          Select.unique(f.asTerm, "apply"),
          (1 to argCount).toList.map(i => Select.unique('a.asTerm, s"_$i"))
        ).asExprOf[b]
      }
    }
```

Testing:

```
val f: (Int, String, Boolean) => String = (i, s, b) => s"$i, $s, $b"
val g = tupled(f)
g: (((Int, String, Boolean)) => String) // checking the type
g((1, "a", true)) // 1, a, true
```

This gives us `curry` for types `(X1, ..., Xn) => Y`

```
curry(tupled(f))(1)("a")(true) // 1, a, true
```

---

Although `curry(tupled(f))` works for a specific `f` it's not easy to specify the signature of a method (composing `curry` and `tupled`)

```
// for match-type implementation of curry

transparent inline def curry1[F](f: F): Any = curry(tupled(f))

curry1(f)(1)("a")(true)
// doesn't compile: method curry1 ... does not take more parameters
```

```
// for type-class implementation of curry

transparent inline def curry1[F](f: F): Any = curry(tupled(f))
// doesn't compile: No given instance of type Curry[Nothing, Any] was found...
// (and what types to specify in (using Curry[???, ???]) ?)
```

I thought that [Recovering precise types using patterns](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#recovering-precise-types-using-patterns) should help if I make `curry1` a macro too

```
transparent inline def curry1[F](f: F): Any = ${curry1Impl[F]('f)}

def curry1Impl[F: Type](f: Expr[F])(using Quotes): Expr[Any] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  '{ tupled[F]($f) } match
    case
      '{
        type t <: Tuple
        $x: (`t` => y)
      } =>
        Expr.summon[Curry[t, y]] match
          case Some(c) => '{curry[t, y]($x)(using $c)}
```

but it doesn't. If `transparent inline def tupled[F](f: F): Any = ...` then `'{ tupled[F]($f) }` doesn't match `` '{...; $x: (`t` => y)} ``. If `transparent inline def tupled[F](f: F): Function1[?, ?] = ...` then `t` is `Nothing`, `y` is `Any`.

So let's make `tupled` an [implicit macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html#given-macros) (type class) in order to control better the return type of `tupled`

```
import scala.quoted.*

trait Tupled[F]:
  type Out
  def apply(f: F): Out

object Tupled:
  type Aux[F, Out0] = Tupled[F] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[F, Out0](g: F => Out0): Aux[F, Out0] = new Tupled[F]:
    type Out = Out0
    def apply(f: F): Out = g(f)

  transparent inline given [F]: Tupled[F] = ${mkTupledImpl[F]}

  def mkTupledImpl[F: Type](using Quotes): Expr[Tupled[F]] =
    import quotes.reflect.*
    val allTypeArgs = TypeRepr.of[F].typeArgs
    val argTypes    = allTypeArgs.init
    val argCount    = argTypes.length
    val returnType  = allTypeArgs.last

    val tupleType = AppliedType(
      TypeRepr.typeConstructorOf(Class.forName(s"scala.Tuple$argCount")),
      argTypes
    )

    (tupleType.asType, returnType.asType) match
      case ('[t], '[b]) => '{
        instance[F, t => b]((f: F) => (a: t) => ${
          Apply(
            Select.unique('f.asTerm, "apply"),
            (1 to argCount).toList.map(i => Select.unique('a.asTerm, s"_$i"))
          ).asExprOf[b]
        })
      }

def tupled[F](f: F)(using tupledInst: Tupled[F]): tupledInst.Out = tupledInst(f)
```

```
// for match-type implementation of curry

inline def curry1[F, T <: Tuple, Y](f: F)(using
  tupledInst: Tupled[F],
  ev: tupledInst.Out <:< (T => Y),
): Curry[T, Y] = curry(tupled(f))
```

Testing:

```
val f: (Int, String, Boolean) => String = (i, s, b) => s"$i, $s, $b"
val g = curry1(f)
g : (Int => String => Boolean => String) // checking the type
g(1)("a")(true) // 1, a, true
```

---

Alternatively to `tupled`, you can try built-in type class `scala.util.TupledFunction` https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/experimental/tupled-function.html (thanks to [@MartinHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152669/martinhh)
for pointing this out in the comments)

```
// for match-type implementation of curry

inline def curry1[F, T <: Tuple, Y](f: F)(using
  tf: TupledFunction[F, T => Y]
): Curry[T, Y] = curry(tf.tupled(f))
```

```
// for type-class implementation of curry

def curry1[F, T <: Tuple, Y](f: F)(using
  tf: TupledFunction[F, T => Y],
  c: Curry[T, Y]
): c.Out = curry(tf.tupled(f))
```

`TupledFunction` is similar to type classes `shapeless.ops.function.{FnToProduct, FnFromProduct}` in Scala 2

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity

[Partial function application in Scala for arbitrary input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215470/partial-function-application-in-scala-for-arbitrary-input-arguments)

[Function taking another function of arbitrary arity as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994624/function-taking-another-function-of-arbitrary-arity-as-argument)

[Scala's type system and the input to FunctionN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213143/scalas-type-system-and-the-input-to-functionn)

Comment: cheers, LOTS of food for thought, cheers. Next question i stumble upon in my studies about fancy typing will go directly to you, Dmytro :D

Comment: @Max See the update with type classes

Comment: I'm studying that psychotrip now ;), cheers! I was seeking for examples like this type-level programming.

Comment: if you have extra time + good will - is it also possible to implement universal `tupled` ? (one like we see in specialized places like `Function.tupled()` ). For learning purposes.

Comment: @Max that is possible with experimental feature `TupledFunction`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/experimental/tupled-function.html#

Comment: By combining that and the code from the answer above, one can easily implement `inline def curry[F, T <: Tuple, Y](f: F)(using tf: TupledFunction[F, T => Y]): Curry[T, Y] = ...` which then will accept non-tupled functions.

Comment: Martin thanks for additional info. I'll drill down into these type-level goodies

Comment: @Max see update about `tupled`

Comment: gold for learning! thx

Comment: @Max See the last update how to define a method `curry1` composing `curry` and `tupled`