# Tuples in Scala 3 Compiler Operations for Typeclass Derivation

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, typeclass, scala-3, generic-derivation

Learning some of the new Scala 3 comppiletime operations and a bit confused about `Tuple` ( particularly using type matching on `*:` and `EmptyTuple`)

```scala
import scala.compiletime.*
imort cats.Show

transparent inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple => (new Show[EmptyTuple] {
      override def show(n: EmptyTuple): String = ""
    }).asInstanceOf[Show[T]]

    case _: (t *: EmptyTuple) => (new Show[t *: EmptyTuple] {
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]

      override def show(tup: t *: EmptyTuple): String = showHead.show(tup.head)
    }).asInstanceOf[Show[T]]

    case _: (t *: ts) => (new Show[t *: ts] {
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      val showTail = showForTuple[ts]

      override def show(tup: t *: ts): String =
        showHead.show(tup.head) + ", " + showTail.show(tup.tail)
    }).asInstanceOf[Show[T]]
```

This works as expected on Scala 3.2.2 for:

```scala
showForTuple[Int *: String *: EmptyTuple].show((1, "hola mundo"))
val res2: String = 1, hola mundo
```

But fails with the following:

```scala
showForTuple[(Int, String)].show((1, "hola mundo"))
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    rs$line$28$$anon$1.show(Lscala/Product;)Ljava/lang/String; @16: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'scala/Product' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'scala/Tuple2'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @16
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'rs$line$28$$anon$1', 'scala/Product', 'scala/Product' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/StringBuilder', 'cats/Show', 'scala/Product' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 2c59 122d b700 302a b600 322b 4d2c
    0000010: b600 38b8 003e b800 42b9 0045 0200 b600
    0000020: 4912 4bb6 0049 2ab6 004d 2b4e b200 522d
    0000030: b600 55b6 0059 b900 4502 00b6 0049 b600
    0000040: 5cb0                                   

  ... 66 elided
```

Learning from: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html and other resources (blog posts/videos)

---

Edit: Thanks to Il Totore in Scala's Discord, the following is a workaround but confused about what was causing the java.lang.VerifyError on the original attempt:

```scala
import scala.compiletime.*
import cats.Show

given Show[EmptyTuple] = _ => ""
lazy val given_Show_EmptyTuple: cats.Show[EmptyTuple]

given [A, T <: Tuple](using showA: Show[A], showT: Show[T]): Show[A *: T] =
  _ match
    case h *: EmptyTuple => showA.show(h)
    case h *: t => showA.show(h) + ", " + showT.show(t)

transparent inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple => summonInline[Show[EmptyTuple]].asInstanceOf[Show[T]]
    case _: (t *: EmptyTuple) => summonInline[Show[t *: EmptyTuple]].asInstanceOf[Show[T]]
    case _: (t *: ts) => summonInline[Show[t *: ts]].asInstanceOf[Show[T]]

showForTuple[Int *: String *: EmptyTuple].show((1, "hola mundo")) // works
showForTuple[(Int, String)].show((1, "hola mundo")) // Also works?
```

Comment: SO is not a bug tracker. Bugs should be reported at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+VerifyError https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: This is not a bug on the compiler, probably a bug on my code (specifically from the `.asInstanceOf[Show[T]]`)

Comment: Well, maybe your code can be improved to avoid casting but if the behavior is different for `A *: B *: ... *: EmptyTuple` and `(A, B, ...)` (which are supposed to be interchangeable), this looks like a bug. Compiler shouldn't generate incorrect bytecode.

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/17169

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/306 M.Odersky about the difference `A *: B *: ... *: EmptyTuple` vs. `(A, B, ...)`: *"The pattern `unapp(a1, ..., aN)` works if `unapp` returns a product match, i.e. a subclass of `Product` that defines selectors `_1, ..., _N`. The `*:` constructor does not produce a product."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more workaround using built-in [method](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.2/library/src/scala/compiletime/package.scala#L170) `scala.compiletime.summonAll` and type-level [operations](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.2/library/src/scala/Tuple.scala) `Tuple.Map`, `Zip` etc.

```
type Ev[T <: Tuple, A] = Tuple.Union[Tuple.Map[T, [_] =>> A]] =:= A

inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  new Show[T]:
    override def show(t: T): String =
      summonFrom {
        case ev: Ev[Tuple.Zip[Tuple.Map[T, Show], T], String] =>
          ev.liftCo[List](
            summonAll[Tuple.Map[T, Show]]
              .zip(t)
              .map[[_] =>> String]([a] => (x: a) =>
                type InstVal[b] = (Show[b], b)
                x match
                  case (s, v): InstVal[?] => s.show(v)
              ).toList
          ).reduce(_ + ", " + _)
      }
```

I had to use `scala.compiletime.summonFrom` because the compiler doesn't know that `Tuple.Union[Tuple.Map[T, [_] =>> A]] =:= A`.

Simpler implementation is with `mkString` instead of `reduce`

```
inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  new Show[T]:
    override def show(t: T): String =
      summonAll[Tuple.Map[T, Show]]
        .zip(t)
        .map[[_] =>> String]([a] => (x: a) =>
          type InstVal[b] = (Show[b], b)
          x match
            case (s, v): InstVal[?] => s.show(v)
        )
        .toList
        .mkString(", ")
```

Here is implementation similar to yours but using [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html). Since match types can't be nested I'm splitting the method into two

```
type ShowForTuple[T <: Tuple] = T match
  case EmptyTuple => Show[EmptyTuple]
  case t *: EmptyTuple => Show[t *: EmptyTuple]
  case t *: ts => ShowForTuple1[t, ts]

type ShowForTuple1[T, Ts <: Tuple] = ShowForTuple[Ts] match
  case Show[Ts] => Show[T *: Ts]

inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: ShowForTuple[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple =>
      new Show[EmptyTuple]:
        override def show(n: EmptyTuple): String = ""

    case _: (t *: EmptyTuple) =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      new Show[t *: EmptyTuple]:
        override def show(tup: t *: EmptyTuple): String = showHead.show(tup.head)

    case _: (t *: ts) => showForTuple1[t, ts]

inline def showForTuple1[T, Ts <: Tuple]: ShowForTuple1[T, Ts] =
  inline showForTuple[Ts] match
    case showTail: Show[Ts] =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[T]]
      new Show[T *: Ts]:
        override def show(tup: T *: Ts): String =
          showHead.show(tup.head) + ", " + showTail.show(tup.tail)
```

One more implementation similar to yours but [using](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#summoning-givens-selectively) `summonFrom` (failing at compile-time) instead of `asInstanceOf` (failing at runtime)

```
inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple =>
      summonFrom {
        case _: (Show[EmptyTuple] =:= Show[T]) =>
          new Show[EmptyTuple]:
            override def show(n: EmptyTuple): String = ""
      }

    case _: (t *: EmptyTuple) =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      summonFrom {
        case _: (Show[`t` *: EmptyTuple] =:= Show[T]) =>
          new Show[t *: EmptyTuple]:
            override def show(tup: t *: EmptyTuple): String = showHead.show(tup.head)
      }

    case _: (t *: ts) =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      val showTail = showForTuple[ts]
      summonFrom {
        case _: (Show[`t` *: `ts`] =:= Show[T]) =>
          new Show[t *: ts]:
            override def show(tup: t *: ts): String =
              showHead.show(tup.head) + ", " + showTail.show(tup.tail)
      }
```

Or returning `Show[T]` in cases, with `@unchecked`

```
inline def showForTuple[T <: Tuple]: Show[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple =>
      new Show[T]:
        override def show(n: T): String = ""

    case _: (t *: EmptyTuple) =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      new Show[T]:
        override def show(tup: T): String = (tup: @unchecked) match
          case (tv: t @unchecked) *: EmptyTuple => showHead.show(tv)

    case _: (t *: ts) =>
      val showHead = summonInline[Show[t]]
      val showTail = showForTuple[ts]
      new Show[T]:
        override def show(tup: T): String = (tup: @unchecked) match
          case (tv: t @unchecked) *: (tsv: ts @unchecked) =>
            showHead.show(tv) + ", " + showTail.show(tsv)
```

[Scala 3. Implementing Dependent Function Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486020/scala-3-implementing-dependent-function-type)

Comment: This is helping me learn a lot thanks. :3

Comment: I can't make **recursive** `transparent inline` works. It doesn't seem to respect precise return type https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/4

Comment: I had issues with [recovering precise types using patterns](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#recovering-precise-types-using-patterns) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418623/express-function-of-arbitrary-arity-in-vanilla-scala-3 too

Comment: Similarly https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/5 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/6

Comment: Thanks a lot for those other examples; looking trough them now.

Comment: If we remove `transparent` and specify return type manually rather than just `Nat` or `Any` this doesn't work https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/11 but works with `summonFrom` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/4yya9TGSS6C80rNo27zEfg/10

Comment: It's this ticket https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/8739